Enforcing OpenAPI spec in implementation of Spring Boot project
I am developing a Spring Boot (WebFlux) project. I have defined API spec using OpenAPI YAML manifest as part of the project.
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Sample API
  description: xxxxx

paths:
  /users:
    get:
      summary: Returns a list of users.
      responses:
        "200": # status code
          description: A JSON array of user names
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: string
  /user:
     get:
       summary: Retrieve a single user.
       response:
            ...
            ...

I wonder if there is a way or a tool that can enforce the API implementation to follow the OpenAPI specification? I mean I firstly define the OpenAPI spec, after which start implementation and enforcing the endpoint parameter types, the order of parameters and payload types based on OpenAPI yaml manifest. I am using WebFlux, thus the code below as an API implementation:
@Component
public class UserClient {

  private final WebClient client;

  ...

  public Mono<String> getUserName() {
    return this.client.get().uri("/user").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(User.class)
        .map(Greeting::getUsername);
  }

}

So, how to enforce the code to comply with the OpenAPI manifest? Any good tooling for this purpose？

In my opinion, you could consider a solution of generating the code in OpenApi, e.g. via a plugin:
https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.openapi.generator
I personally use the code below to generate code between microservices based on OpenApi json files:
task buildXyzClient(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask) {
generatorName.set("java")
extensions.add("x-spring-paginated","true")
typeMappings.put("OffsetDateTime","Instant")
importMappings.put("java.time.OffsetDateTime","java.time.Instant")
inputSpec.set("$rootDir/serviceDefinitions/XYZ/v1/openapi.file")
outputDir.set("$buildDir/generated")
generateApiTests.set(false)
generateModelTests.set(false)
apiPackage.set("xyz")
invokerPackage.set("xyz")
modelPackage.set("xyz")
configOptions.set([
        dateLibrary: "java8",
        useJakartaEe: "true",
        openApiNullable: "false"
])
library.set("resttemplate")}

You can redirect outputDir to your project dir and change resttemplate to webclient using config:
https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java/
